# In rails how to Insert thousands of records in table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have created API using Ruby on Rails. when I call an API endpoint to insert more than 1000 records it gets crashed.
currently, I am using database `Mysql2`

my code is

```
quantity.times do
  User.create(first_name: "John")
end
```

where `quantity` is a number of records need to insert and it can be any number like 10000, 4000000.

can anyone suggest me how can I do this very efficiently without breaking my server

Comment: Post the error message, log or stacktrace if possible.

Comment: I get this error on my `Production`  it doesn't show any particular error message. but server get crashed, my backend is n Ruby on Rails and for frontend, I am using AngularJS

Comment: You are doing it as background job?

Comment: @AnkurPohekar Feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you, as well as for future SO searchers. :)

Answer (score 4):

[ActiveRecord.import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import)

```
items = []
quantity.times.each do |row|
  items << User.new(name: "john")
end
User.import(items)
```

Just have a look at these [benchmarks](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/wiki/Benchmarks) to get a sense of just how much faster this option is. Instead of separate transactions, commits, and inserts that a  `Model.create` generates SQL for, this handles it in a single query.

References

- https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/wiki
- https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activerecord-import/ActiveRecord/Base

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can use [find_each](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each][1])
and specify the batch_size to loop it.

I think it will prevent the crash in case you loop a huge amount of quantity same as your example

Comment: I am not finding anything I am doing an insertion

Comment: User.find_each(start: 1, finish: quantity.times, batch_size: 500) { |user|  user.create(first_name: "John") }

Comment: ah, sorry. I checked on my rails console and this is not help you :)

Answer (score 0):

try this **gem 'activerecord-insert_many'**. In the source code, find tests and you can see how to consume the gem.

Thanks,
Ajith